# How to remove the comma at the end of the sentence in Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

```
for i in range(5):
  print(i,end=',')
```

O/P : 0,1,2,3,4,

#I want to remove the comma after printing 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(*range(5), sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove the comma after it has been printed.

You could use `','.join([str(i) for i in range(5)])`